# FTP users stored in IIS

Tags: sql, authentication, iis, ftp

I need a little guidance on what I can do with an FTP site I am creating.

Essentially the FTP is to provide data that end users have requested.  Workflow is as follow:

User selects what data they want -> User's info (contact, requested data/formats, custom user and password string) stored in SQL table -> Email sent to FTP manager with unique ID of end user -> FTP Manager runs script using unique ID as input, generating the requested data -> Data stored in directory on FTP server and email sent to end user with credentials for obtaining data.

So far, everything up to the credentials part of my workflow is working.  The FTP uses no authentication as of right now (because I'm not sure what needs to be done to do so).

My question is, is it possible for me to create IIS users to access the FTP site using the user/password string I create when the end user makes the request, that way I can use some authorization on the FTP site?  Am I even approaching this in the correct manner?  I'm no IIS/DB guru but I know enough to break something.

What I think I should do:
Set the authentication to use IISManagerAuth, and with magic create the IIS users based off of the credentials I create from the end user request (This is what I am going to try and do while you smart folk point and laugh at my lack of understanding and blindness of the inevitable).

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: For the record, I have looked at the following:
[link]http://forums.iis.net/t/840879.aspx?FTP+User+Scripting [link]http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/905498e5-e017-41fc-b8fa-85890eddd489.mspx?mfr=true [link]http://hsphere.parallels.com/docs/3.1/sysadmin/html/14784.htm  With the last one being the most interesting.  Looking into cpanel now.

Comment: I think that you are approaching this in the wrong manner.  A better approach would be to use .net or php or coldfusion or something similar to write your site.  They will all provide functionality that will make the security part simpler.  For example, they will enable you to encrypt passwords.

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk, I have contemplated creating the entire site in .net, and just connecting to the DB to verify login credentials.  However, one feature in IIS I liked was the ability to filter what contents are shown based on the user login. This would work perfectly with my setup. If I go with a .net site, would replicating this feature be easy enough for a novice developer?

Comment: So we have decided to omit the creation of FTP users via script.  We do not process a great number of requests, so simply creating a windows user, then setting the specific user read access to the FTP in IIS (all manually) is our approach.  We will then have a script fire nightly which checks our data request table for the time stamp of the request, and if it's been x days, the user (and requested data) will be removed.